# How to handle routeProvider, with GET api call that can be bookmarked?

Tags: angularjs

Here is my route provider:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/', {templateUrl: '/partials/search.html'}).
                when('/about', {templateUrl: '/partials/about.html'}).
                when('/services', {templateUrl: '/partials/services.html'})
                //otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
                ;

        }])
```

I'm running searches on /partials/search.html. I want that the searches can be bookmarked. So I added this to the code where I receive the ajax response of my search:

```
$location.path(myGetQuery);
```

But, well, this triggers the routeProvider and it doesn't load any fragment and the view is left empty. With `otherwise... redirect` it will show the blank search fragment / url and my search query is gone.

I also tried something like this...

```
$routeProvider.
   when('/', {templateUrl: '/partials/search.html'}).
   when('/:pars', {templateUrl: '/partials/search.html'}).
   when('/about', {templateUrl: '/partials/about.html'}).
   when('/services', {templateUrl: '/partials/services.html'});
```

And well, thanks to `/:pars`, `$location.path(myGetQuery);` makes the page load with the correct url (with the query), but the fragment is still reloaded, and since I'm executing this after I get the response of the search, my result is gone.

What is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$location.search` to change querystring values of the url. See the documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location#search).

Basically, after your search is complete you do something like this, which will update the url to: `...?q=foobar`.

```
$location.search({ q: 'foobar' });
```

In your case you might want to take the object you pass into your ajax query and pass that into search.

When you enter your route, you can use `$location.search()` to extract existing values (in case they have a url bookmarked) and then perform the search based on those.

**Update**

As per comment, you also need to update your route to include `reloadOnSearch: false`.

Comment: I don't know if I understood you correctly. When I call `$location.search(query)`, this triggers the routeProvider and it loads the template again. So my search results are gone.

Comment: Ahh... I just found that you can pass `reloadOnSearch: false` to the route... looking better

Comment: I didn't actually think you'd need to set that, but I tested and as you say you do. I'll update the answer.